# while-loop could not be stopped (probably, additional problems that I have not recognize may occur)

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I try to find an array (front_design_array) having been built by adding the elements of (array) to (f_ext_ele_groups). When the sum of any element in (f_ext_ele_groups) equals to 10, it is appended to (front_design_array). The sum of an element in (front_design_array) should not be bigger then 10. If an element bigger then 10, it is not added to (draft) list which is built for next iteration by assigned to (f_ext_ele_groups). But some mistakes that I couldnt recognize occured. While-loop does not end.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
f_ext_ele_groups= [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]
                          
front_design_array=[]          
length=len(f_ext_ele_groups)    
while length > 0:               
    
    for var in f_ext_ele_groups:
        
        sumation = sum(var)
        
        if sumation ==10:
            front_design_array.append(var)
    
        elif sumation < 10:
            draft= []
            for ele in array:
                if int(var[0]+ ele) <= 10:
                    draft.append([var[0], ele])
                else:
                    continue

    f_ext_ele_groups=draft
    length=len(f_ext_ele_groups)
```

Comment: Your ```draft``` is not redefined as empty  when ```summation == 10```, which means that it takes the value from when ```summation == 9```

Comment: Could you please share what output, you are expecting from this sample data?

Comment: something like that front_design_array= [[1,1,6,2], [2,5,3], [3,7], [4,3,2,1], [5,5], [6,4], [7,3], [8,2], [9,1], [10]]

Comment: Is this the exact answer that you are expecting? because I could not able to find any logical relation between find outcome? please confirm?

Comment: After tweaking above program I am currently getting the following outcome: [[10], [4, 1, 2, 3], [7, 1, 2], [9, 1], [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2, 3, 1], [6, 1, 2, 1], [8, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1], [5, 1, 2, 1, 1]]

Comment: Still trying to figure out at my end though

Comment: This is not a solution. But may give some clue to debug and fix your logic:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/17RNxxUpNyNEbSkgDCeq8YcmmQVS7qq60KCUXC7ev0d8/edit?usp=sharing

I'm still not able to find resemblence in your input vs output.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of first loop you've got

```py
f_ext_ele_groups = [[9, 1]]
```

because `draft = [[9, 1]]`.

So, in next turn, `length > 10` is true, and this comes into

```py
sumation = sum(var)
```

because sum of that only one inner element is `10`.

So this

```py
front_design_array.append(var)
```

is only called, and `draft` is not changed at the end of the loop. So it's repeated again, and again, etc.